# SQL Inner Join with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

So I believe I need a Inner Join for this query, but am not 100% sure.

**First of all see my database diagram:**

[Click here for database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ0eQ.png)

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

- I'm trying to get all messages (so user_username, text, posted_at FROM Messages) where the user_username matches with the followed_username, and where the followed_username has a follower_username that = ?.
- So essentially, everyone followed by ?, I want to get all their messages.

Where ? = an inputed username

**What I've tried so far**

I've tried a number of sql statements and have thus far been unable to get be successful. These are some I have tried.

```
$sql = "SELECT user_username, text, posted_at FROM Messages, Users, User_Follows WHERE user_username = (SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = (SELECT followed_username FROM User_Follows WHERE follower_username = ?)) ORDER BY posted_at DESC;";
$sql = "SELECT user_username, text, posted_at FROM Messages, User_Follows WHERE follower_username = ? AND followed_username = user_username;";
$sql = "SELECT user_username, text, posted_at FROM Messages JOIN User_Follows ON user_username = followed_username WHERE follower_username = followed_username;";
```

I now think I need to use an inner join to achieve what I want, but am not too sure whether this is correct, or how to go about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have right now is cross joins which is your problem. Under no circumstances should you ever use implicit joins. They are a very poor technique and cause problems like this.  To offer a fix  we need to see the table structures.

Comment: Have you looked at my link @HLGEM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT M.user_username, M.text, M.posted_at 
FROM Messages M  
INNER JOIN Users U on  M.user_username= u.username
INNER JOIN User_Follows UF  on UF.followed_username = u.username
WHERE UFfollower_username = ? 
ORDER BY posted_at DESC;
```

Note for future designs that using a long varchar or nvarchar field is a poor choice for a field you will be joining on. Further, if the field is a character type field, it is often subject to being changed over time which is also a bad choice for a key field.

Integer joins are much faster generally. It might be ok if it can save you from having to to do some joins but in general it is a poor idea.

If someone changed his username (which does happen in every system I have ever worked in) you would then have to update all the child tables which could be quite a lot of records to update. If you used a surrogate key, you would only need to update the parent table.

Additionally the word text is a reserved word for many databases and it is best to avoid those in naming fields.

Comment: Thanks, great answer

Answer (score -1):

a simple sub query should do it:

```
select * from messages where user_username in
(
  select followed_username from user_follows
  where follower_username = 'your_input_username'
);
```

Comment: I would upvote this is you removed teh SQL antipattern of select *

Comment: @edlerd Gives an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN (SELECT followed_username FROM User_Follows WHERE follower_username = 'kris')'